# DataGridView in C# WinForm

Tags: c#

I have datagridview on my winform. I have data from some other processes coming frequently that need to be printed on datagridview. Which datagridview event fires frquently where I can print my data? Is it possible by some event or some other approach is required?

Comment: [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) can fire event frequently.

Comment: Why dont you just trigger what you want to trigger when the data goes into the datagridview?

Comment: In general it's easiest to bind the grid to a bindingsource and update that source. The source will fire the appropriate events (assuming a source such as BindingList<> is used). The only pitfall is asynchronous updating. If the source is updated from another thread than the thread in which the grid is created, errors are to be expected. (In that case you could use a flat list and `Invalidate()` the grid when updated or in a timer)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a methode which is called everytime you need to print the datagridview.

```
dt2.Rows.Clear(); //clear datagridview
//dt2 is a datatable
//here u can load your data into a datatable or what every you want
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
```

Put this code into a methode a call it everytime you need it. (e.g. timer every 5 sec)

Comment: My datagrid is a logger and I want to keep the data even someone is closing the application. Whenever someone is opening this, the previous data should persist and continue to log new data with new operations. How to do this?

Comment: u could safe it in a text file or something similar and read this file when u open the application.

Comment: My requirement - logger which is winform with datagrid control used to display data from other applications. Other applications are just sending the string that need to be captured on logger whether logger is running or not. When user is opening logger, all data should be displayed . You mean to say that I need to write all data to a text file and update logger with this text file. Right?